# How to Update "Created By" column through workflow?

Tags: list, workflow, list-view, custom-list, blog

I am trying to make the Blog comments and discussion replies to be Anonymous. The only way to do this (a simple way) is through hiding the created by column in the view. Is it possible to update the created by column through workflow? When I tried to update this list item, created by column is not displayed in the options. Picture is given below. How to update created by or effectively hide the author from the comment?

[image]

Comment: Can only be done via server side code iirc.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Read Only field of this list in SharePoint Manager in your server, and use a workflow to change it.