# Cannot update Created By (Author) field through powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to add a new item to a SharePoint list AND set the created by/author field. I don't have much experience with powershell but this seems fairly straightforward.

I have a 2013 environment and a list called Favorites that users populate with links they want to save. However, I'd like to be able to add a favorite for a user as read and edit access is limited to items created by the user.

My powershell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint";
$SPList = $SPWeb.GetList("http://sharepoint/Lists/Favorites");
$userName = "i:0#.w|[domain]\[username]";
$user = Get-SPUser -web $SPWeb -Identity $userName;

$SPListItem = $SPList.Items.Add();
$SPListItem["URL"] = "http://www.cnn.com";
$SPListItem["Author"] = $user;
$SPListItem.Update();
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid data has been used to update    
the list item. The field you are trying 
to update may be read only."
At line:11 char:1
$SPListItem.Update();
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SPException
```

If the field has a read only property, I thought it would be possible to change that:

```
$SPList.Fields["Author"].ReadOnlyField = $false;
```

However, that gives me this error:

```
Property 'ReadOnlyField' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is
settable.
At line:6 char:1
$SPList.Fields["Author"].ReadOnlyField = $false;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Edit: after further investigation, there were recent security updates made to our SharePoint server by our network admin that may be related to this script no longer working. I will try to update this post with what I find out.

Any ideas are still appreciated.

Edit 2: see below for the solution I used.

Comment: https://splistitemeditor.codeplex.com/ works for me a few times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is what I needed to change to get this to work:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepoint";
$SPList = $SPWeb.GetList("http://sharepoint/Lists/Favorites");
$userName = "i:0#.w|[domain]\[username]";
$user = Get-SPUser -web $SPWeb -Identity $userName;
$userString = "{0};#{1}" -f $user.ID, $user.UserLogin.Tostring()

$SPListItem = $SPList.Items.Add();
$SPListItem["URL"] = "http://www.cnn.com";
$SPListItem["Author"] = $userString;
$SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

$userString is the correct format for the user and using UpdateOverweiteVersion() instead of update() saved the changes to the Author field.

Answer (score 3):

Please, refer to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tadd/archive/2008/05/22/updating-the-created-by-and-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx) to modify this field:

```
$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint")
$SPWeb = $SPSite.OpenWeb()
$SPFieldUserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($SPWeb,8, "#Test R.Test") 
$ListItem["Author"] = $SPFieldUserValue                   
$ListItem.Update() 
$SPWeb.Update()
```

As you can see, you must create a **SPFieldUserValue** as mentionned above. The number '8' is the user ID (you get it from `Get-SPUser` I guess -cannot test it right now-, or please check SPWeb users -`$SPWeb.users` ?-).

Other point, please check the `$SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates` value. Must be to `true`otherwise you won't be able to modify the `ReadOnly` property. According to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/100557/17814

Comment: You don't need to create a new object for that. You can just do: $user = $web.EnsureUser("Domain\User")

Answer (score -2):

Try adding an update right after creating the record....

```
$SPListItem = $SPList.Items.Add();
$SPListItem.Update();
$SPListItem["URL"] = "http://www.cnn.com";
$SPListItem["Author"] = $user;
$SPListItem.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but that still gives the first error message above.

Comment: You may need to create the items first...and then loop through and update the values.

See here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-SharePoint-list-4e6272ab