# How do I update CreatedBy field of List Items based on criteria?

Tags: list, powershell

I need to update the CreatedBy field of a number of list items based on the criteria of Title and another user defined field. If I could run some powershell similar to the following it would be great.

```
Update List
Set CreatedBy = 'domain\new_username'
where title = 'xxx'
and userField = 'yyy'
and createdBy = 'domain\old_username'
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this post:

[Cannot update Created By (Author) field through powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130636/cannot-update-created-by-author-field-through-powershell)

Basically you need to get a reference to the item, then do something like this:

```
$SPListItem["Author"] = $userString;
$SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below mentioned code will help you to update `Author` based on some conditions.

```
// Get the SharePoint Assembly
// You will need to run this on the SharePoint Server

[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

// The site my list was in was at http://dev
// create a new object called $SPSite

$SPSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://dev/")

// Make sure you have the last “/” in the url on the site
// allow $SPWeb to be the OpenWeb from the site

$SPWeb = $SPSite.OpenWeb()

// Get the list ModifyCreatedBy

$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["ModifyCreatedBy"]

// Get the Collection of the List Items

$SPListItemCollection = $SPList.Items

// iterate the Collection

foreach ($ListItem in $SPListItemCollection)
    {
if($ListItem["title"] -eq "xxx" -And $ListItem["userField"] -eq "yyy" -And $ListItem["createdBy"] -eq "domain\old_username")
{
// The user in this case was Test R. Test and had a user id of 8 from the SPWeb users
//

        $SPFieldUserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($SPWeb,8, "//Test R. Test")

        $ListItem["Author"] = $SPFieldUserValue                   

// Note: Editor will be the account that you are running the Powershell under unless you update // Editor as well

        $ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
}
    }

    $SPWeb.Update()

// Still TODO Disposes, Error Checking, Change to take Parameters, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, using @Mohamed and @Hardik's answer.. I scripted the following which allowed me to update the "Created By"

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://server/site"

    $userName = "i:0#.w|domain\username";
    $user = Get-SPUser -web $SPWeb -Identity $userName;
    $userString = "{0};#{1}" -f $user.ID, $user.UserLogin.Tostring()

    $SPList = $SPWeb.GetList("http://server/site/Lists/ListName");
    $SPListItemCollection = $SPList.Items;
    foreach ($ListItem in $SPListItemCollection)
    {
        if ($ListItem["Title"] -eq "xxx" -AND $ListItem["OtherField"] -eq "yyy" -AND $ListItem["Created By"].Contains("PartialName"))
        {
            $ListItem["Created By"] = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($SPWeb, $userString);        
            $ListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
        }
}
```

Comment: BTW, this is the same solution which i provided in my answer. :)

Comment: @hardik, it is not since you are using SSO objects, and the code above relies  in great portion on PowerShell cmdlets

Comment: It's the same as in the code I referred to you in the other post ;)